# Magento 1.9 - Dashboard Last 5 Orders missing Guest Name

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, dashboard

Since the upgrade from Magento 1.7 to 1.9, we are not seeing Guest Name under the Last 5 Orders in the Admin Dashboard.   I've read that this is because the name is now stored as a whitespace instead of NULL.

I need a way to fix this as I do not know where this record is written at.   I'd prefer a way that will not break if we upgrade again.

Comment: When you say the Gust Name, is this a custom column in that section, or is it the name under Customer? Is the value missing for only orders placed by guests, or also registered customers?

Comment: It is the name column.  For registered users the name will display, but not for anyone who checks out as a guest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Don't edit core files; extend them instead.)

You can use the billing address name by editing the following:

1. `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Orders_Grid::_prepareCollection()`

   Replace `joinCustomerName` with `joinCustomerBillingName`
2. `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection`

   Add function:

   ```
   public function joinCustomerBillingName($alias = 'name')
   {
       $fields      = array('t2.firstname', 't2.lastname');
       $fieldConcat = $this->getConnection()->getConcatSql($fields, ' ');
       $this->getSelect()
       ->join(array('t2' => 'sales_flat_order_address'),'main_table.billing_address_id = t2.entity_id')->columns(array($alias => $fieldConcat));

       return $this;
   }
   ```

   [Source](http://developerafroz.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/magento-show-guest-name-in-last-5.html)

Comment: Where is the file to change?  I know you mentioned not editing the core file (and I agree 100%).   Thus, I believe I need to make a copy of the file and put it in a new location so if you could provide the original filename (with full path) and the path to the new location it would be tremendously helpful.

Comment: The local path would be `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Orders/Grid.php`. However, instead of copying the entire file, which would still make it "immune" to upgrades, I'd encourage you to extend it and only edit the function(s) you need to. There's a good article, [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/).

Comment: In v1.9.3.0 and possibly earlier: When extending Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Orders_Grid::_prepareCollection(), you must also change the return to: `return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Grid::_prepareCollection();` or the Grid will not be populated using your changes.

Comment: If your order links stop working from the Dashboard grid, this line in the above function needs to be changed:
$this->getSelect()->join(array('t2' => 'sales_flat_order_address'),'main_table.billing_address_id = t2.entity_id'**, array()**)->columns(array($alias => $fieldConcat));

Comment: Finally, if you use table prefixes in your DB, then remember to change `sales_flat_order_address` in the above given function to `prefix_sales_flat_order_address`.